# Meteor Settings in Apache / Passenger

Tags: apache, meteor, passenger

I have a apache2 server and tryed to use it with passenger to start my meteor application. Meteor and everything runs fine but I wished to use a setting file or at least a setting object. So I tryed it with **SetEnv** but it doesn't work cause apache escapes the object.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sub.site.de

# Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's code directory is
DocumentRoot /var/www/app/bundle/programs/web.browser
PassengerAppRoot /var/www/app/bundle

# Tell Passenger that your app is a bundled Meteor app
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile main.js
# PassengerMeteorAppSettings /var/www/app/settings.json < doesn't work also
# Tell your app where MongoDB is
SetEnv MONGO_URL mongodb://localhost:27017/app
# Tell your app what its root URL is
SetEnv ROOT_URL http://sub.site.de
SetEnv METEOR_SETTINGS "{uploadPath:'/var/www/app/upload'}"
# Relax Apache security settings
<Directory /var/www/app/bundle/programs/web.browser>
  Allow from all
  Options -MultiViews
  # Uncomment this if you're on Apache > 2.4:
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The meteor settings get escaped. When I call the page it crashes with:

```
/var/www/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:324
}).run();
   ^
Error: METEOR_SETTINGS are not valid JSON: {uploadPath:&apos;/var/www/app/upload&apos;}
    at packages/meteor.js:59:11
    at packages/meteor.js:80:4
    at packages/meteor.js:1358:3
    at /var/www/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:283:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/var/www/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /var/www/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:133:5
```

Someone knows how to handle it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late reply, but could prove useful to someone in future :)
You have to pass settings as proper JSON, so they have to be double quoted. Proper line for you will be then:

```
SetEnv METEOR_SETTINGS '{"uploadPath":"/var/www/app/upload"}'
```

As it has to be valid JSON syntax, not JavaScript object and all the properties and String values have to be double quoted here.

Please note that providing too long config (it occured to my project) will break Nginx, throwing an error about configuration line being too long.